How to convert .docx file to .pdf in python?
I am developing an android app that outputs pdf file. I use chaquopy module to create a .docx file from string and convert it to .pdf. The most suitable option for now is aspose, but it outputs a file with watermarks, which is not ideal for my app. Are there any other modules that are capable of doing it without a watermark and for free? Maybe there are free modules to create pdf files from text without watermarks?

You can use ReportLab. I think it is best option for you.
